# how to share common definition between c and tcl

Tags: c, automated-tests, tcl

For testing purposes, I need to share some definitions between Tcl and C. Is it possible to include C style include file in Tcl scripts? Any alternative suggestion will be welcomed, but I prefer not to write a parser for C header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWIG supports Tcl so possibly you can make use of that. Also I remember seeing some code to parse C headers on the Tcl wiki - so you might try looking at the [Parsing C](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3906) page there. That should save you writing one from scratch.

Comment: found in another place: "Tcl has its own excellent interface to C code. I would recommend to just study it instead of wasting time on SWIG. " , But did not find anything yet, so i still have a hope for some #include like syntax that i just can't find, never used tcl in my life :) Will investigate some more ...

Comment: That is referring to the ease of extending Tcl to work with external libraries. Its very easy to extend tcl but you said you just want to share some definitions. As C is strict, you need to implement some basic parsing of the .h file - possibly just regex matching will suffice. If you want a full interface, calling DLL methods from Tcl - then you should be writing an extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a full API of any complexity, you'd be best off using SWIG (or critcl<sup>†</sup>) to do the binding. SWIG can do a binding between a C API and Tcl with very little user input (often almost none). It should be noted though that the APIs it produces are not very natural from a Tcl perspective (because Tcl *isn't* C and has different idioms).

Yet if you are instead after some way of handling just the simplest parts of definitions — just the `#define`s of numeric constants — then the simplest way to deal with that is via a bit of regular expression parsing:

```tcl
proc getDefsFromIncludeFile {filename} {
    set defs {}
    set f [open $filename]
    foreach line [split [read $f] "\n"] {
        # Doesn't handle all edge cases, but does do a decent job
        if {[regexp {^\s*#\s*define\s+(\w+)\s+([^\s\\]+)} $line -> def val]} {
            lappend defs $def [string trim $val "()"]
        }
    }
    close $f
    return $defs
}
```

It does a reasonably creditable job on Tcl's own headers. (Handling conditional definitions and nested `#include` statements is left as an exercise; I suggest you try to arrange your C headers so as to make that exercise unnecessary.) When I do that, the first few definitions extracted are:

```
TCL_ALPHA_RELEASE 0 TCL_BETA_RELEASE 1 TCL_FINAL_RELEASE 2 TCL_MAJOR_VERSION 8
```

---

<sup>†</sup> Critcl is a different way of doing Tcl/C bindings, and it works by embedding the C language inside Tcl. It can produce very natural-working Tcl interfaces to C code; I think it's great. However, I don't think it's likely to be useful for what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you're thinking about integrating structure or function definitions, definitely look at SWIG. Unfortunately, you'll probably have to put extra Tcl code around the interface produced by SWIG. (For example, SWIG does not convert integers that are really flag sets into the natural Tcl equivalent, a list of flag words.)

Comment: Thanks, I just need share defines so probably your suggetion and parsing example will be good enough.